# Quickest way to process large number of files with thousands of Data in each file

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, file

I need to process data from some large number of file with thousands of data in terms of rows.Earlier i was reading the whole file row by row and processing.It took a lot of time for processing all the file when the number of files increased.Then some one said that threads can be used to perform the task in less amount of time??Can threading make this process fast.I'm using c# language.

Comment: Process them how? Into a db or some other way?

Comment: Where's your bottleneck? If it's disk IO, then threads could concievable make it slower. (I'm making assumptions about your setup here...)

Comment: Notice that when you read all the file data then analyze this data is better than reading it row by row..

Comment: each row of a file has 2 phone numbers which needs to be checked in the Db and then written back to another file

Comment: You should provide more information for example.. files are comma delimitted, Tab delimited, fixed length, variable length, etc... Threads are good too but I believe that the most important question should be what kind of file / file info are you trying to process

Comment: Each row of file is fixed length.Its actually the call details of phone numbers through a hardware switch.So each row means a call detail.So we need to collect info from each file such as calling number and called number and then collect data related to those numbers from the database and write to another file

Comment: @MohammedShraim if the files are huge and the computer's memory is not, then it will not be possible to read the entire file at once.

Comment: @MohammedShraim i need to analyse each row of file for specific details and perform respective operations as per information so cant read all file  data at once.

Comment: you are facing a performance issue and multithreading will increase the problem on files, for blocking and unlocking the files will consume more time from CPU. and also through the same thread if there is 1 million record you will need 1 million access to the file which will consume CPU time also. so i suggest to find the best number of rows to get like 100 or 1000 then make a loop on the memory to handle this records.

Comment: @MohammedShraim could u explain wat u mean by "find best number of rows"

Comment: @Gray how can i accept solutions which don't solve the problem

Comment: Read the link please.  It's about the best solution that helps you.  If they really are bad then you should answer and accept your own solutions.  Otherwise others that look at your questions/answers for posterity aren't helped.

Comment: our friend (phoog) add comment talking about the memory if we read the whole files at once.. so if its contain a million record this will lead to memory leak, so find the best number of rows to get every time in while loop (until EOF) like 1000 every time, and the appropriate number of row according to the data exist in each row -number of column in another words-.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can although it depends on the particular job in question.  A very common pattern is to have one thread doing the file IO and multiple threads processing the actual lines.

How many processing threads to start will depend on how many processors/cores you have on your system, and how the results of the processing get written out.  If the processing time per line is very small however, you probably won't get too much speed improvement having multiple processing threads and a single processing thread would be optimal.

Comment: The 'processing' of the line involves communicating with the DB, so it could potentially be beneficial to have more threads than processors so that while one thread is blocking on a DB call another can be setting one up, doing file IO, etc.

Comment: Agreed @Servy although you may find that it only takes a couple of worker threads to turn your program from being IO bound to being database bound.

Comment: did you mean the reverse?  I would imagine that it would start out database bound, not IO bound.  With enough worker threads you may be able to turn change that to IO bound, depending on how things are setup, what the hardware specs of everything is, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear.  Right now you are mostly IO bound from the standpoint of your file reading, network if remote database, and database writing.  At some point with enough workers, you are going to max out your database's capacity to handle the load.

Comment: Yes, your thread max should be based on the number of requests the DB can efficiently support. This will be based on the latency of the communication with the database, the complexity of the query (as well as the data that it touches and whether or not the queries overlap in the data that they touch), the hardware specs of the DB, etc.  In practice, you can just run the program with various thread pool sizes and compare the times.  Rather than academically guessing a an optimal value I'd go with an experimental mechanism. (Either way, it won't be strongly tied with the number of cores).

Answer (score 1):

Good thing with performance question is to assume that your code is just doing something unnecessary and try to find what it is - measure, review, draw - whatever works for you. I'm not saying that the code you have **is** slow, it just a way to look at it.

With adding multithreading to the mix first you may find it to be much harder to analyze the code.

More concrete for your task: combining multiple similar operation (like read a record from file or commit to DB) together **may** save significant amount of time (you need to prototype and measure).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you do batch insert to your database.

You can have a thread that reads a line to a concurrent queue. while other thread is pulling the data from concurrent queue. agregating it if necessary or if you are doing any operation on it. then batch insert the data to database. it will save you quite a time.

Inserting a line to db would be very slow. you have to do batch inserts.

Comment: we r not actually inserting data line by line into db.We process the whole file and write processed data completely into another file then do a Load infile into the Db.

Comment: OK. i dont know ur impl detail but if you want to increment your IO performance look at Asynch IO such as beginXXX methods. other than that there is not much you can to for IO bound ops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using threads can speed thigns up.
Threads are to be used when you have time onsuming tasks you can run in the background (like, when you process say 10 files, but only need one, you can have a thread process each of them which will be a lot faster then processing them all on your main thread).

Please not that there may be bugs related, so you should make sure all threads finished running before continuing and trying to access what they got.

Look up "C#.NET multithreading"
any thread can run a specified function, and background worker is a nice class as well (I prefer pure multithreading though).

Also note that this may backfire and wind up slower, but it's a good idea to try.

Comment: Using multiple threads could be a mistake here; especially for disks. This could cause the disk to hammer as it performs random rather than sequential access, and greatly decreases the effectiveness of the buffer

Comment: Maybe, but it's still a good idea to try it. In any case that MIGHT happen, but might not. The goal here is increasing efficiency, if it succeeds in that, let it be. If not, undo the changes and find alternate ways, right?

Answer (score 0):

Threading is one way (there are others) of letting you overlap the processing with the I/O. That means instead of the total time being the sum of the time to read the data and the time to processing the data, you can reduce it to (roughly) whichever of the two is larger (usually the I/O time).

If you mostly want to overlap the I/O time, you might want to look at overlapped I/O and/or I/O completion ports.

Edit: If you're going to do this, you normally want to base the number of I/O threads on the number of separate physical disks you're going to be reading from, and the number of processing threads on the number of processors you have available to do the processing (but only as many as necessary to keep  up with the data being supplied by the reader thread). For a typical desktop machine, that will often mean only two threads, one to read and one to process data.

Comment: The 'processing' of the line involves communicating with the DB, so that's most likely going to be the bottleneck.  File IO will be fairly small in comparison, so there really isn't any need to overlap the IO.  It would at best not change a thing.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, looking through the comments, and the fact that his "processing" deals with a DB, that's probably the place he needs to spend his effort.